# ssh backspace not working until I manually run TERM=xterm

Tags: bash, ssh

I understand that backspace might now work in an `ssh` session if `TERM` is set incorrectly. But strangely, I have a server where `TERM` is set correctly, but backspace does not work until I manually set `TERM=xterm` in the shell (which should be redundant). See here:

```
~ ] ssh root@192.168.10.40
root 192.168.10.40 / # echo $0
-bash
root 192.168.10.40 / # echo $TERM
xterm-256color
root 192.168.10.40 / #     # backspace does not work :(
root 192.168.10.40 / # 
root 192.168.10.40 / # TERM=xterm-256color
root 192.168.10.40 / # # now backspace works!!
root 192.168.10.40 / # logout
```

I would say about 90% of the time, backspace does not work until I run `TERM=xterm`, and 10% of the time, I don't need to run the `TERM=` command because backspace is already working. I've compared the output of `env` for each case, and they are identical (aside from `SSH_CLIENT` and `SSH_CONNECTION` where only the client side port has changed)

Any idea what may cause this behavior, or what a workaround might be?

---

**Response to comments**

I am using `OpenSSH_6.8p1, BoringSSL` from `https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/openssh`, and I am running `GNU bash, version 4.3.42(1)-release (arm-android-eabi)` from `https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_external_bash.git`

`stty -a` shows no different before and after setting `XTERM`. Output is:

```
speed 38400 baud; rows 102; columns 319; line = 2;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff -iuclc -ixany imaxbel -iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke
```

`bind -p|egrep 'delete|rubout|kill'` also shows no different before and after setting `XTERM`. Output is:

```
"\C-h": backward-delete-char
"\C-?": backward-delete-char
"\C-x\C-?": backward-kill-line
"\e\C-h": backward-kill-word
"\e\C-?": backward-kill-word
# copy-region-as-kill (not bound)
"\C-d": delete-char
"\e[3~": delete-char
# delete-char-or-list (not bound)
"\e\\": delete-horizontal-space
# forward-backward-delete-char (not bound)
"\C-k": kill-line
# kill-region (not bound)
# kill-whole-line (not bound)
"\ed": kill-word
# shell-backward-kill-word (not bound)
# shell-kill-word (not bound)
# unix-filename-rubout (not bound)
"\C-w": unix-word-rubout
# vi-delete (not bound)
# vi-delete-to (not bound)
# vi-overstrike-delete (not bound)
# vi-rubout (not bound)
```

Interestingly, if I `source` my `bashrc`, my backspace starts working again. I know the `bashrc` is being sourced on login though because that is the only place where I set my `Ps1` value

Comment: what's the server? SSH server name and version?

Comment: your shell may run a script to update the prompt, and in that script the `TERM` value might be used to update the terminal settings.

Comment: Could you do "stty -a" before and after the assignment, and see if there is any difference?  Just a try to debug.

Comment: One other thing that will help people: The outputs of `bind -p|egrep 'delete|rubout|kill'` run before and afterwards.

Comment: An application could be initializing the terminal, sending `\033[?67h` (or `033[?67l`) aka DECBKM.  If you check what is actually sent (use `cat -v` to make the key readable, using `^V` to help), does *that* change?

Comment: When I run `cat -v` and then type `CTRL+V` then `Backspace`, I see `^?` each time. Is this what you meant?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like readline/terminal interaction, start by checking your `.inputrc`, `/etc/inputrc`, `/etc/default/login`, `INPUTRC` environment variable during the login process, and then readline bindings (via `bind -q backward-delete-char`).

No harm double checking what's in the client (ssh_config) `SendEnv` and server (sshd_config `AcceptEnv`) directives too, if anything (though `TERM` is not sent from client to server this way in OpenSSH, the client always includes the `TERM` value in the session setup, and the server set `TERM` from that). The occasional presence of `TERMINFO` or `TERMCAP` in the environment is the only thing I can think of to explain the intermittent nature of this.

Readline applies "rubout" to whatever the terminal declares its "erase" is, and rubout is what readline invokes via `backward-delete-char`.

`TERM` is one of the special variables that bash monitors, when it's set (independent of whether it *changes*) [bash resets the terminal](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/variables.c?h=bash-4.4&id=a0c0a00fc419b7bc08202a79134fcd5bc0427071#n5181):

```
/* What to do just after one of the TERMxxx variables has changed.
   If we are an interactive shell, then try to reset the terminal
   information in readline. */
void
sv_terminal (name)
     char *name;
{
  if (interactive_shell && no_line_editing == 0)
    rl_reset_terminal (get_string_value ("TERM"));
}
```

(where "`TERMxxx`" means `TERM`, `TERMCAP` and `TERMINFO`) so this explains why simply setting `TERM` to its current value actually performs an action.

If you cannot track it down, adding "`TERM=${TERM}`" at the end of your `.profile`/`.bashrc` might be a work-around.

As a last resort you could also try some forensic measures, as detailed in my answer here: [Monitor and alert user when stty settings change?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/179509/monitor-and-alert-user-when-stty-settings-change)